# Which version of the DLL file should I use in HoloLens?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, hololens

I am very new in developing HoloLens's app. In my development project, I need to add many other references in Visual Studio 2017. But I don't know which versions of these references should be selected. The versions of these DLL files are .Net 4.6.1 and .Net standard 2.0. HoloLens is UWP, so I have to choose .Net Core or .Net standard 2.0 DLL files? Is .Net 4.6.1 not compatible with HoloLens?

The version of software i am using is:

1.Unity 2018 3.11f

2.MRTK V2.0.0 RC1

3.Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Could you explain why you are needing to add references to your generated project? Unity will automatically create the references you need for your project when you build for UWP.

Comment: To see how to use Unity to create a UWP for Visual Studio, follow the instructions here: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html

Comment: @Julia Schwarz Thank you for your reply, I want to use HoloLens to connect OpcUa and Mysql servers, so I need to add their references externally, but I don't know which version of the reference to use to be compatible with HoloLens.